# How to use merge layer "concatenate" with Keras 2.0?

Tags: concatenation, keras

I am currently trying to update [this densenet implementation](https://github.com/titu1994/DenseNet/blob/master/densenet.py) for Keras 2.0. Everything works, except for

```
from keras.layers import Input, merge
[...]
concat_axis = 1 if K.image_dim_ordering() == "th" else -1

feature_list = [x]

for i in range(nb_layers):
    x = conv_block(x, growth_rate, bottleneck, dropout_rate, weight_decay)
    feature_list.append(x)
    x = merge(feature_list, mode='concat', concat_axis=concat_axis)
    nb_filter += growth_rate

return x, nb_filter
```

I changed it to

```
from keras.layers import Input, concatenate
[...]
feature_list = [x]

for i in range(nb_layers):
    x = conv_block(x, growth_rate, bottleneck, dropout_rate, weight_decay)
    feature_list.append(x)
    x = concatenate(feature_list, axis=concat_axis)
    nb_filter += growth_rate

return x, nb_filter
```

But this gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run_training.py", line 87, in <module>
    config=experiment_meta)
  File "/home/moose/GitHub/msthesis-experiments/train/train_keras.py", line 74, in main
    model = model_module.create_model(nb_classes, input_shape)
  File "/home/moose/GitHub/msthesis-experiments/models/densenet.py", line 173, in create_model
    densenet = Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=x, name="create_dense_net")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1700, in __init__
    str(layers_with_complete_input))
RuntimeError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("conv2d_2/convolution:0", shape=(?, 32, 32, 12), dtype=float32) at layer "concatenate_1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: ['input_1', 'initial_conv2D', 'batch_normalization_1', 'activation_1', 'conv2d_1']
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed with https://github.com/fchollet/keras/commit/c2321e61e1732f7a27841eca36cdaf34ed5d26dd.

In the meantime you can use

```
x = concatenate(feature_list[:], axis=concat_axis)
```